# Syntax highlighting in a Jupyter kernel for a custom language

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I'm writing a custom Jupyter kernel for a small DSL. The kernel itself is mostly based on [IHaskell](https://github.com/IHaskell/IHaskell) as long as the reference implementation of the DSL is in Haskell, and mostly works. Now I'm struggling with adding syntax highlighting to my notebooks. Jupyter uses CodeMirror, and there's a [tutorial](https://codemirror.net/examples/lang-package/) how to create a new parser package using the parser generator called Lezer, but I couldn't find how to properly load the resulting parser in my kernel. IHaskell itself [seems](https://github.com/IHaskell/IHaskell/blob/master/html/kernel.js) just to take the Haskell mode bundled with previous versions of CodeMirror with different API, so it's of no help.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have a similar question for a DSL+custom kernel and have thus far found it surprising difficult to answer.